# Rsync with date filter over ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, rsync, date, filter

I use the following command successfully

```
rsync -e 'ssh' -avr root@192.168.3.227:/home/mikrotik /bck/mikrotik/
```

How can I add date filter to this command? I would like to sync only files that are newer than *n* days from remote dir `root@192.168.3.227:/home/mikrotik` to local dir `/bck/mikrotik/`

Comment: I don't think that is easily doable with `rsync` alone. BTW, you don't need `-e ssh` as SSH is the default. And `-r` is already activated by `-a`, so you can drop that as well.

Comment: Unless you intentionally delete files periodically from `/bck/mikrotik` that are still present on the source system, or you have many thousands of files and you're seeing a time impact while `rsync` skips the files it's already transferred, your date filter shouldn't be necessary

Comment: If you want to limit the process to files newer than n days (and there are older files in the source that are absent in the target), you can use for example `find -mtime -7` as a filter before the copy process to get files created/modified during the last 7 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you intentionally delete files periodically from `/bck/mikrotik` that are still present on the source system, or you have many thousands of files and you're seeing a time impact while `rsync` skips the files it's already transferred, your date filter shouldn't be necessary.

However, having said that you can use `find` to generate the set of candidate files for transfer. Here we're considering only files that have been created/modified within the last seven days:

```
ssh -n root@192.168.3.227 'cd /home/mikrotik && find . -type f -mtime -7 -print0' |
    rsync -av --files-from='-' --from0 root@192.168.3.227:/home/mikrotik /bck/mikrotik/
```

If you don't have a version of `find` that supports `-print0`, replace it with `-print` and remove `--from0` from the `rsync`. The difference is that you then won't be able to copy files containing an embedded newline in their name

Comment: Thank you @sudodus fixed

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you @roaima. That's exactly what I needed.